# Создание графического интерфейса Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk

Я написал приложение на Java в Android Studio, делает оно всё то, что мне нужно, но вот дизайн его графического интерфейса меня печалит. Набор графических элементов крайне скудный и я очень хочу сделать его привлекательнее.
Есть такие идея написать View на React, а Model и Controller на Java (Как собственно уже и написано).

Дайте дельный совет, как быть в такой ситуации, желание учить новое всегда есть :)

Да, хотелось бы отменить, что есть опыт написания интерфейса на Cordova с помощью CSS3/HTML5 + JS, но скорость работы сами понимаете какая. Однако сама связка этих трех языков дает шикарный результат в плане дизайна. В моей голове ситуация бескомпромиссная :(

Comment: с помощью кастомизации нативных виджетов можно сделать им абсолютно любой внешний вид и функциональность, хотя пользователи обычно плохо относятся к самопальной кустарщине на экране и делают выбор в пользу родного дизайна Material. Всякие реакты и кордовы в андроид-приложении будут печалить вас куда сильнее, когда вы будете пытаться использовать их на практике

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал использовать стандартный гугловый дизайн ([material](https://material.io)), если рассматривать с точки зрения конечного пользователя - ведь он каждому интуитивно понятен и создаётся целостность системы android

Comment: Да, но ведь чтобы сделать например график, описывающий какое-то состояние онлайн, таких вещей в стандартном дроиде нету, как их реализовывать?

Comment: @Meepo для этого существует gcharts, так же от Гугла